# Parsing JSON string in Swift 2

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I am working on a project in Swift (just learning Swift to be exact)

and have to extract and display the JSON output of an API.

Here are the API spec/example

[API Documentation](https://developer.nutritionix.com/v1_1/quick-start/upc-scan)
https://developer.nutritionix.com/v1_1/quick-start/upc-scan

and here is the code so far -

```
let url = "https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/item?upc="

        let urlWithUPC = url + barcode + "&appId=[YOURID]&appKey=[YOURKEY]"

        print("API Query: "+urlWithUPC)

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlWithUPC)!) { data, response, error in
            // Handle result
            print("Checked the bar code")

            let itemDescription = (((data as NSArray)[0] as? NSDictionary)?["item_description"] as? NSString)
            print("Item Description :" + itemDescription)
            }.resume()
```

Right now, I just want to scan the UPC (which works), look up the item (which works), get data back (which works), and then extract and display the desired portion of the data (not working).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `data` is an `NSData` object (raw bytes) you have to deserialize it with `NSJSONSerialization`

Comment: The NSJSONSerialization fixed the issue.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put your `AppID` and `Secret` into the URL yet.